# Do real vectors attain matrix norms?

Tags: linear-algebra, banach-spaces

I apologize if the following question ends up being too elementary for this website; I [asked it](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103160/do-real-vectors-attain-matrix-norms) on math.SE a week ago and it remains unanswered.

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix with real entries and let $p \geq 1$. I'm wondering if 
$$ \max_{ x \in \mathbb{C}^N, \|x\|_p = 1} \|Ax\|_p$$ is the same as

$$ \max_{ x \in \mathbb{R}^N, \|x\|_p = 1} \|Ax\|_p.$$
The only difference is the replacement of $\mathbb{C}^n$ by $\mathbb{R}^n$. Certainly, the answer is yes if $p=1,2,\infty$; on the other, it is pointed out [in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/104461/9182) that the answer is no for mixed $(p,q)$-norms.

Edit, Will: I can't get this stupid thing to work. On MSE, Robert Israel introduced a $p,q$ mixed matrix norm with suitable notation, where the vectors $x$ are measured with the $p$-norm, but the $Ax$ are measured with the $q$-norm.

Comment: I don't think it's true for reals. Otherwise, Perron-Frobenius would be a stupidly weak assertion.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being thick, but is there a connection between Perron-Frobenius and matrix norms? I thought Perron-Frobenius tells us that the largest eigenvalue of a nonnegative matrix is real, which is only a lower bounded for its $p$-norms. 

Comment: Ah, I thought you were speaking of the "standard" matrix norm. What is the $p$-norm of a matrix? Hilbert-Schmidt with $p$ instead of $2$?

Comment: As currently constituted, there are no matrix norms in the question; only $p$-norms of vectors - these, presumably, are unambiguous


Comment: @Anthony, Yemon put in the matrix norms from MSE, and I attempted to typeset Robert Israel's p,q matrix norms, which was a flop, so I just described those in words. Note that the precise nature of what was answered on MSE and what was left conjectural really ought to have been described in full by the OP. 

Comment: @Will: I didn't change any of the text, I just added a tag

Comment: @Yemon, I looked at the edit history, I see what you mean. Well, people who are better than I am at combining Latex and MO could put in Robert Israel's notation for, really, all the matrix norms. I have no idea what I did wrong.

Comment: Doesn't this paper: http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0512608v1.pdf  answer the question (Theorem 3.1 specifically)?

Comment: @Florian, I think you may be right. Consider making that a full answer and explaining a bit about dropping to finite dimension. I notice Holtz takes $p < q.$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, so basically the answer can be found in here: http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0512608v1.pdf

Here's how the argument works (a simplified version of what is done in the paper with finite dimensions and $p=q$):

*(Note: we define "$\Re$" of a vector by taking the real part componentswise)*

Lemma 3.4 says (applied to the finite dimensional situation)
$$
 \int_0^{2\pi} \| \Re(e^{i\varphi} x) \|_p^p d\varphi = \int_0^{2\pi} |\cos(\varphi)|^p d\varphi
$$
for any $x\in \mathbb C^n$ with $\|x\|_p=1$. This is fairly elementary to verify.

Therefore, whenever $x,y\in \mathbb C^n$ both have norm $1$, we will find a $\varphi\in[0,2\pi]$ such that $$\|\Re(e^{i\varphi}x)\|_p \leq  \|\Re(e^{i\varphi}y)\|_p$$
since the integral
$$
   \int_0^{2\pi}\|\Re(e^{i\varphi}y)\|_p^p - \|\Re(e^{i\varphi}x)\|_p^p d\varphi = 0
$$
is zero und thus the integrand has to be non-negative somewhere.

Then Lemma 3.2 of the paper yields the result. What the authors do here is to take a vector
$0\neq x\in \mathbb C^n$ such that $\|Ax\|_p/\|x\|_p$ is maximal *(assume also that $A\neq 0$; then $Ax\neq 0$ follows automatically and we can divide by its norm below)*. Then they take a $\varphi$ such that 
$$
 \left\|\Re(e^{i\varphi} \frac{x}{\|x\|_p})\right\|_p \leq \left\| \Re(e^{i\varphi} \frac{Ax}{\|Ax\|_p})\right\|_p
$$ 
which is possible by the above. If $\Re(e^{i\varphi}x)\neq 0$, this can then be rewritten as 
$$
 \frac{\|Ax\|_p}{\|x\|_p} \leq \frac{\|A \Re(e^{i\varphi}x)\|_p}{\|\Re(e^{i\varphi}x)\|_p}
$$
which shows that the maximum is also attained at the real vector $\Re(e^{i\varphi}x)\in \mathbb R^n$.
If $\Re(e^{i\varphi}x)=0$, then $i\cdot e^{i\varphi}x$ is a real vector at which the maximum is attained.